# Laravel | Get specified data for current page

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I'm trying to get meta data for each page
Each page has a unique slug

In `appServiceProvider` I have:

```
$view->with('seopage', Page::all());
```

In blade view (section head) I have:

```
<title>
  @foreach($seopage as $sm)
    {{ $sm->main_title }}
  @endforeach
</title>
<meta name="description" content="
  @if(Request::is('/*'))                             
  @foreach($seopage as $sp)
  {{ $sp->site_description }}
  @endforeach
  @endif
">
```

But it is getting `all titles` and `descriptions` for me at the moment. How can I get data for specified page?

Page model have `unique SLUG variable`. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean `have unique slug variable`? Can you post your `Page` model?

Comment: you are sending all pages information to every blade. that is why you got all titles. if you want to filter it you have to do it on appServiceProvider.

Answer (score 2):

In `appServiceProvider` you can share page which belongs to specified page:

```php
$page = Page::where('slug', Request::path())->first();
View::share('seopage', $page);
```

And in view you can retreive shared variable:

```
<meta name="description" content="
  @if(Request::is('/*') && isset($seopage))
  {{ $seopage->site_description }}
  @endif
">
```

Answer (score 0):

You must be have unique uri column in seopage table

The you must be use

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

.....

$uri = \Route::current()->uri;
$seopage =  Page::where('uri', $uri)->first();

if ($seopage) {
    $seo = sprintf(
        '<title>%s</title>'  . PHP_EOL
        . '<meta name="description" content="%s>',
        $seopage->main_title ,
        $seopage->site_description
    );
} else {
    $seo = '';
}
$view->with('seo', $seo);
```

In Blade use

```
{{ $seo }}
```